# Java System Tray With NO Icon

Tags: java, icons, system, tray

I know how to add my application to the System Tray.

However, I do not have an icon to use, so how would I do this if I cannot use the TrayIcon?

Is there a way I can use a built-in Java icon?

Comment: It looks bland when you don't have any system tray icon and it may confuses the user. You can include an icon inside your Java application jar or from external folder and cache it as `ImageIcon` using `ResourceBundle()`. It is really easy to create an icon using freeware icon editor like IcoFx.

Comment: I know, but for the application that I am designing, I do NOT have ANY icon that I can use. Is there a way that I could download a Java icon and use that instead? You know, the Java icon that displays when you open an applet?

Comment: yes, I believe that official Java icon is an embedded resource item of any java tool under Java \bin folder (java.exe, javaw.exe, etc.). I am not sure whether we can extract it from the java tool with a third-party application. Is it allowed to use the copyrighted material?

Comment: I have provided an answer and see whether it fits your problem or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract an icon from an executable in the following link:

http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/02/get-file-type-icon-with-java.html

Make sure to consult on the right to use the copyrighted material before you do that.